# About using MongoDB and Linq. What's better or worse with Norm?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'd like to use MongoDB with Linq, simply because I do not like to not being able to check the query at compile time.
So I searched a bit and found Norm. However I am having a hard time deciding if it's "safe" to move from the official driver.

So I was wondering if can someone tell me the key differences between the official driver and Norm ?
Also what can Norm do that the official driver can't ?
Is it possible to implement Linq on top of the official driver ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use mongodb official driver because it will contains all latest features and any issue will be fixed asap. As i know last commit in norm repository was almost a half of year ago, so.. If you want linq support you can use [fluent mongo](https://github.com/craiggwilson/fluent-mongo) at the top of the official driver, but i believe that linq support should be soon in official driver.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'll try out fluent mongo.